# Rails form_for and has_many through argument error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a form_for to create a join model between two other models. I have a Book model and User model, with another called Reads that is my join. Here is how I've set up the associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reads
  has_many :books, :through => :reads
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reads
  has_many :users, :through => :reads
end

class Read < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I've looked at the docs for form_for and watched the railscast episode on many-to-many associations, but I can't figure out why I'm getting the error when I try to render the Book#show view where I've put the form:

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

Here is my form in app/views/books/show.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@read) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :book_id, value: @book.id %>
  <%= button_to 'Add to Reads', {controller: 'reads', action: 'create'}, {class: 'btn'} %>
<% end %>
```

I think part of the problem is that I am trying to create a 'Reads' object from the Books model, but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I need the 'Add to Reads' button on the Book's page so that a user can select that particular book to add to their 'reads.' I'm also adding the current_user id in the controller, rather than in the view. Here is my create action from the Reads controller if that helps...

```
def create
  @read = Read.new(read_params)
  @read.user_id = current_user.id
  @read.save
  if @read.save
    # do this
  else
    # do that
  end
end
```

And I'm using strong params...

```
def read_params
  params.require(:read).permit(:user_id, :book_id)
end
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

This means that `@read` in your form is `nil`.  Since you are in the show action of your Books controller, you have to define this variable in the books controller.

```
def show
  @read = Read.new
  ...
end
```